# exponential equation to solve ($2^{x+1}\ + 3) (2^{x-1} -5) = -19 $

Tags: exponential-function

($2^{x+1}\ + 3) (2^{x-1} -5) = -19 $

I multiplied and got:

$2^{2x}\ - 5 2^{x+1} + 3 2^{x-2} - 15 = 19 $

And then, I subtracted 19 from both sides to get:

$2^{2x}\ - 5 2^{x+1} + 3 2^{x-2} + 4 = 0 $

I got stuck here. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'd write $y$ for $2^x$.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: This is easy to solve knowing that you must have a positive times a negative and simply plugging values in and checking...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Make the substitution $y = 2^{x - 1}$. What does $2^{x + 1}$ become?

---

**Full solution:**
We get
$$
(4y + 3)(y - 5) = -19.
$$
Expanding and rearranging gives
$$
4 y^2 - 17 y + 4 = 0
\implies y^2 - \frac{17}{4}y + 1 = 0
$$
yielding
$$
y_{1} = \frac{1}{4}
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
y_2 = 4.
$$

Undoing the substitution we now have for $i \in \{1,2\}$ (and $y > 0$)
$$ \tag{$\star$}
y_i = 2^{x_i - 1}
\iff x_i = \log_2(y_i) + 1
$$
and therefore we get
\begin{gather}
x_1 = \log_2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) + 1
= \log_2(2^{-2}) + 1
= -1 \\
x_2 = \log_2(4) + 1
= \log_2(2^2) + 1
= 3.
\end{gather}

Answer (score 1):

$2^{2x}-5\times2^{x+1}+3\times2^{x-1}-15=-19\implies2^{2x}-10\times2^x+\dfrac32\times2^x+4=0$

$\implies y^2-\dfrac{17}2y+4=0$, where $y=2^x$ as suggested by [Lord Shark the Unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436618/lord-shark-the-unknown).

Can you take it from here?